# Flutter voice input in flutter

Tags: flutter, input, voice

I want to take input in voice format like this : g9gzApgKAefkClF4HBMQjLlhAy9BCf2DEnkBtZYIp0wb2Cghy3CKG6D0msCz7oHw9QQmng1ZBAMDOB8iMDPQIXnzQLEtgnRhB/P2AhOUBxcomZNwQ2gg/YTGIv6CYvMZlU4xUJQcjDgGaXAfLqB1F4n5k=" to pass voice data with API. I tried many packages of flutter but failed. Is there any method of doing that?

I tried flutter_speech,http,audioplayers,mic_stream these packages  of flutter.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i want ot make API requst , and the paylod is in this format "HFVgLNrARtCATQsBDUIAM/wHkzgOdFADNuCLlkBUuIDSSwKXsgCAzBCTaApekAGqoD1uQAwPgESfAChqBc00A/G4EbrQEzHgJkzAfoKBaR8A3poHUqwAyDgOJpAmy+CZWMCJmYIX+QFITgRspAdDWAO9ECkJIG4ewD6ygDITAqFKARicAUfoFfMwJXcguiNBA/eApbEB7e4PLJQImXgtqXBaRCAJREDwLoL7lwRDggNgrAL/GBrmUE8vYM2RQecNgozxApwGBQzcDLToQ7BwqSUg9gzApgKAefkClF4HBMQjLlhAy9BCf2DEnkBtZYIp0wb2Cghy3CKG6D0msCz7oHw9QQmng1ZBAMDOB8iMDPQIXnzQLEtgnRhB/P2AhOUBxcomZNwQ2gg/YTGIv6CYvMZlU4xUJQcjDgGaXAfLqB1F4n5k="